# Insert an object in a list using MongoTemplate

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following structure :

```
{ 
    "_id" : "adddddddddddd", 
    "_class" : "com.fluidm.service.identity.entity.Item", 
    "itemName" : "satyam", 
    "personList" : [ ]
}
```

I have a collection let say "item" having list of persons which are internally stored in MongoDB as an array.

I want to insert a person object or bunch of person objects into the list using **MongoTemplate** approach.

I've tried the push method but didn't work.

```
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is("​adddddddddddd")), new Update().push("personList", person), Item.class);
```

PS : I don't want to use native approach to insert data.

Answer (score 7):

Replace the field name of the entity with the name that I specified in @field annotation for the fields. The reason is MongoTemplate detect those fields with the names that actually stored in DB.

```
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is("​adddddddddddd")), new Update().push("person_list", person), "item");
```